# Cleaning Line Noise of Captcha Images With Python

Tags: python, captcha, opencv

[image]

Im trying  to remove line on this captcha images, so i can use OCR tools like tesseract to read the string text on image.
I use code that have explained at [How I developed a captcha cracker for my University's website](https://dev.to/presto412/how-i-cracked-the-captcha-on-my-universitys-website-237j) and Image Enhance so have better look to recognize image.
Here my python code so far (I'm new with python actually)

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance


im = Image.open("img2.png")
nx, ny = im.size
image = im.resize((int(nx*5), int(ny*5)), Image.BICUBIC)
image.save("img1_enchance.png")

image = image.convert("L") # Grayscale conversion
width, height = image.size
cropped_image = image.crop((0, 0, (460/3), 200))
cropped_image.save("img1_crop.png")

pixel_matrix = cropped_image.load()
croppedwidth, croppedheight = cropped_image.size
for col in range(0, croppedheight): # Height
    for row in range(0, croppedwidth): # Width
        if pixel_matrix[row, col] != 0:
            pixel_matrix[row, col] = 255
cropped_image.save("img1_text1.png")

for column in range(1, croppedheight - 1):
    for row in range(1, croppedwidth - 1):
        if pixel_matrix[row, column] == 0 \
            and pixel_matrix[row, column - 1] == 255 and pixel_matrix[row, column + 1] == 255:
            pixel_matrix[row, column] = 255
        if pixel_matrix[row, column] == 0 \
            and pixel_matrix[row - 1, column] == 255 and pixel_matrix[row + 1, column] == 255:
            pixel_matrix[row, column] = 255
cropped_image.save("img1_text2.png")
```

The problem is, instead got the text string, Im got the noisy line like picture below:

(img1_text1.png)

[image: img1_text1.png]

(img1_text2.png)

[image: img1_text2.png]

I have the collected captcha images like below in this [google-drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19LlWdoYSMMw8Gi9AkhTHNOe8L5FR5VUF/view):

[image]

Any help very appreciated, thank you so much

Comment: And why exactly should we help you bypass somebody's CAPTCHA? They are there for a reason.

Comment: OK, my goal was to use code from the tutorials and learning cv2.. And actually use solution for automatic login into website